# How to interpret information in brackets in Xorg.0.log?

Tags: xorg, logs

Are the numbers inside the blocks are in some sort of date format?

```
[  1613.015] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event16)
[  1613.015] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1613.015] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1613.016] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event17)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a timestamp. It indicates the time since the system last booted, in seconds.

If you are running Linux then you can find the same number as the first field of the contents of `/proc/uptime`.

Comment: Any idea why an event that happened just now in the Xorg says `[2123343.758]` while uptime says `6418311.05 204951697.98` (System's been up for 74 days and does not sleep or hibernate). `Xorg` has been running for ~7 days and gdm for 74 days. Nothing correlates with 24 days ago - Fedora 33

Comment: @Andy: the timestamp from Xorg wraps around after ca. 49 days (when the time gets larger than 2^32 milliseconds). This fits very well to your system uptime; so maybe you see the timestamp from the gdm-started Xorg. Btw. sorry for resurrecting this old post, but the info might be useful to other people :-)