# Convert Xorg log timestamps to human readable timestamps

Tags: kernel, x11, logs, timestamps

I need to change the time stems of a whole Xorg/X11 log file (e.g. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) into human readable format. The default format is [the time in seconds since boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180407/how-to-interpret-information-in-brackets-in-xorg-0-log?newreg=d06a95807590437ba6e5342c75072ff1), preferably yyyy-mm-dd + time. The solutions would ideally work over different boot sessions.

What I tried or thought of:

1. tried `dmesg -T -F Xorg.0.log`: this did not convert the timestamps
2. search for Xorg version of dmesg: did not find anything
3. writing a script: I might do that in the end, but I don't want to write something which already exists.
4. Use `/proc/uptime` to get the current time since boot: Does not help me because I want to see the logs from before reboots

Are there any tools which can do this task for me or help me with it?

Comment: 1. Timestamps are seconds from boot 2. Why do you need that exactly?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I need it for finding the logs around an event, but now I am more interested in how to do it (i.e. how to make that readable). If you know how to do the first part better, it would be cool if you could tell me here in the comments.

Comment: I'd use perl, get the last timestamp in the file, assumed to correspond to the last modification time of the file and do calculations from there. Best would be to convince Xorg to output the timestamps in a more useful format.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : Done… a long time ago with no luck : please read : https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28429 in particular Alan Coopersmith's answer.

Comment: Unrelated : your Xorg logs sit in /var/log ? Would you still be running the xorg-server as root ?

Comment: @MC68020 I am not sure what you mean^^'

Comment: Implemented @StéphaneChazelas idea in python here: https://gist.github.com/scm2409/798b1a09fc0f54e8e4ec7bf9138b584a

Answer (score -1):

While, depending on your expectations, your might find your way among some answers of [this other U&L_SE related thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/correlating-var-log-timestamps),
In particular [this one which more or less implements the idea suggested by Stéphane as part of OP's commments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10495/426539),
You will realize that all those methods exhibit flaws because the kernel time is not incrementing during suspend-to-ram periods.

So… in case this just does not matter for you… do proceed.

Stéphane rightly suggested that the best way would be to request freedesktop.org to produce more useful timing information, [this has been done in the past with no luck](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28429)
RFC closed for the reason that:

> Unfortunately, human friendliness is limited by the functions that can
> be safely called in a signal handler, which prevents use of
> strftime().

Comment: Thanks for the extra context! Is only the dmesg the kernel time or does this susped-to-ram stop also apply to x11 logs?

Comment: @SebastianDonnerWolfBach : Yes indeed. As a matter of fact, it applies to whatever log relying on relative timestamps.